# Angularjs $eval does not always work

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know when can I safely use method $eval (declared in AngularJS $rootScope.Scope).
I don't undestand the difference between these two examples.

In [example 1](https://plnkr.co/edit/YkSmw7WyXXskfQajEyHt), {{$eval(expr)}} works as expected:

```
<li ng-repeat="expr in exprs track by $index">
  [ <a href="" ng-click="removeExp($index)">X</a> ]
  <code>{{expr}}</code> => {{$eval(expr)}}
</li>
```

In [example 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlExSP2oYTcIvBzQuX3u), {{$eval(name)}} produces empty string:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></label><br>
  Hello {{$eval(name)}}!
</div>
```

Note: if you replace "$eval(name)" by "name" in example 2, the result will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is why, but in the first example, ng-repeat creates a variable for expr that's in scope within the ng-repeat. In the 2nd example there's nothing to explicitly keep name in scope, so it stands to reason that a straight up evaluation of it would fail. Apparently when an expression is enclosed in quotes $eval is kind enough to evaluate it within the context of the current scope.

At any rate, the rule is that if you're referencing a variable (or some other expression) that's in scope, then quotes are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In example 2, you are evaluating the value in the name property on the scope.  $eval returns and empty string when given a string that is not an expression.  If the value in the input box was 'Whirled' instead of Whirled, then it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
Now my answer is as follows.

In example 2, AngularJS replaces name by Whirled. 
As an argument of $eval, this is NOT the expression (despite it looks like uninitialized field Whirled of some $scope), so $eval produces the empty string.

Next question: if you use eval(name) instead of $eval(name), it will produce the empty string as well.
Why not 'undefined'?